Computing working days between different periods of time
I am a basic PowerBi user. I want to build a Health and Safety dashboard incluiding the severity index defined as working days lost by an accident.
Let's say that we have an accident occurred on march, 3th and the employee returns to work on March, 6th. In this case we can compute 4 working days lost in March.
On the other hand, if we hav an accident occurred on March, 26th and the employee returns to works on April, 3th, we compute 6 working days lost in March, and 3 working days lost in April. The grand total is 13 working days lost.
To simplify we consider all days are working days.
We have two tables, one which is the working days calendar (CalendarioBaja), and the other which is the accident table (Eventos), incluiding four fields [employe Id, eventDay, startDate (FechaBaja), finishDate(FechaAlta)]
I've tried two methods to compute the total working days lost and get two different results.
The first one
Build a new independent table called "working days lost" using the DAX function GENERATE, as follows:
Working days lost =
GENERATE(
Eventos,
FILTER(
CalendarioBaja,
CalendarioBaja[Date] >= Eventos[FechaBaja] &&
CalendarioBaja[Date] <= Eventos[FechaAlta]
)
)
I can represent data with a matrix like this:

Date hierarchy in the first column
Employee Id in the rest of the columns
Year aggregated by count as the value

First method result
The result is ok, but I don't think this is the best method, instead, I would like to   calculate the value using a measure, and here comes the second method.
The second one
Define a measure for counting the number of working days lost (JP) as follows:
JP = COUNTROWS(
GENERATE(
Eventos,
FILTER(
CalendarioBaja,
CalendarioBaja[Date]>=Eventos[FechaBaja] &&
CalendarioBaja[Date]<=Eventos[FechaAlta]
)
)
)
In my opnion this measure should give the same result but as shown in the image, although the grand total is ok, data for April don't appear in the matrix.
Second method result
I don't know what I'm missing, so I would appreciate any help or indicataion about this issue.
Thank you in advance.
Diego

I believe you have a relationship between CalendarioBaja[Date] and Eventos[eventDay]. In your measure you will need to remove this relationship via CROSSFILTER function.
Try the following:
JP = 
  var tbl =
    CALCULATETABLE(
      GENERATE( Eventos, FILTER( CalendarioBaja, CalendarioBaja[Date]>=Eventos[FechaBaja] && CalendarioBaja[Date]<=Eventos[FechaAlta] ) ),
      CROSSFILTER('CalendarioBaja'[Date], Eventos[eventDay], None)
    )
  return COUNTROWS( tbl )

